# Show that the integral of the product of a continuous and integrable function can be expressed purely in terms of the integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

Suppose that $f:[a,b]\rightarrow R$ is continuous and $g:[a,b]\rightarrow R$ is integrable
and such that $g(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$. Prove that there is a number $c$
in $[a,b]$ such that

$$
 \int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx = f(c)\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx
$$

My proof:

Consider $F(x) =f(x)\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx$, $F$ is continuous since it's a scalar multiplication of $f$. Moreover, $m\int_{a}^{b}g(x) \le \int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx\le M\int_{a}^{b}g(x)$, if $m\le f(x)\le M$ (by extremum value theorem).

The statement follows by an application of Intermediate value theorem on $F$.

I suspect that my proof is flawed since I didn't use $g(x)\ge 0$ in my proof (at least not explicitly). Could you please check my attempt and give me hints to why it's flawed? I prefer hints to complete solutions.

Comment: Why is $m \int_a^b g(x)\,dx \leqslant \int_a^b f(x)g(x)\,dx$?

Comment: It's because $m \le f(x) \le M$ on the interval $[a,b]$ and if $ f(x) \le g(x)$, then $\int f(x) \le \int g(x)$.

Comment: So why is $m g(x) \leqslant f(x)g(x)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Ahhh. Thank you!